# Compare Result of compare editor without the UI

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I want to use the compare result of the Compare Editor in Eclipse and interpret in my own way. From what I see the comparing is tightly coupled with the UI. Is there a way I can use the compare API and not the UI aspects that is offered with it?

Comment: You could probably use the `org.eclipse.compare.structuremergeviewer.Differencer` and `org.eclipse.compare.rangedifferencer.RangeDifferencer` classes directly.

Comment: @greg-449 - Thanks. I want to compare files, text files to be precise. I explored your options but somehow file comparison is not happening. Any other ideas?